# rminer package, error in Importance() duplicate 'switch' defaults: 'lm == func...' and 'NULL'

Tags: r

I am trying to learn the R package 'rminer'. It provides three functions; 'fit' and 'predict' to basically fit and predict and a more powerful one which combines these two 'mining'. Further this package provides a function 'Importance()' to measure input importance including sensitivity analysis, and a piloting function to graph the result 'mgraph(model,graph="IMP",...)'

When I produced results with fit() function I can successfully use the Importance() and mgraph() functions.

However, when I use the mining() function I can only use mgraph() to visualize the measured input importance and I failed to produce results using Importance() function. I believe if I can plot the input importance results then I should be able to print/save their numeric values using Importance() though I'm receiving the following error

```
  MM=mining(formula,data,model=models,Runs=Runs,method=v,mpar=m,search=s,task=task,feature=feature)
I=Importance(MM, data, method="1D-SA")
Error in Importance(MM, data, method = "1D-SA") : 
  duplicate 'switch' defaults: 'lm == func...' and 'NULL'
```

and I couldn't find many results through searching www to lead me a solution.

I really appreciate if you can guide me how to use the results of mining() function in Importance() if this is possible.

Thank you.

Son

Comment: Hi,I also tried to use this importance function for svm regression model and got the same error. Did you managed to find a way to run this function or find a way to do a feature selection from a model?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution to the problem.